# Angular2 datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am a new for angular2, and I like it.
I am trying to use a datepicker for angular2 application.
I tries some of the components such as ng2-datepicker and mydatepicker, and none of them could not follow easily.

Could you provide very step-by-step instruction for this problem?

Comment: Did you tried ng2 bootstrap date picker ? https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

If you want to try other datepicker then you can use datepicker from ng2-bootstrap. Steps are follows-

Install package using - `npm install --save ng2-bootstrap`

Install moment.js typings - `typings install moment --save`

In systemjs.config.js, you update config like this-

```
map: {
  moment: 'node_modules/moment/moment.js'
}
```

In Index.html add this line-

```
<script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

DatepickerModule as imported module in your application module app.module.ts

```
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
// or
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker';
```

In html template-

```
  <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="dt" [showWeeks]="true"></datepicker>
  </div>
```

In component you can set dt like this-

```
public dt:Date = new Date();
```

For more details refer this [link](https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

ng-bootstrap is quite a nice library built by angular guys.
Basically it's created to support bootstrap css without using their jquery part.

It has similar datepicker and other components that match with Bootstrap look-wise and functionality-wise.

Quite easy to install and great support from the makers. Look at their documentation and some samples beneath the configuration.
[@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker)

Dont forget to see the samples, it's far below as you scroll down, after a lot of configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng2-bootstrap http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/
but I feel is not good
So, you can use datetimepicker with bootstrap:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
      @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <div>
          <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
          <input type="date" value={{todate}} class="form-control" (change)="changeInput($event.target.value)" /><br />
          <span>{{showdate}}</span>
        </div>
      `,
      providers: [DatePipe]
    })
    export class App {
      name:string;
      todate: any;
      showdate: any;
      constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
        this.name = 'Angular2'
        this.todate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd')
      }
      changeInput(event){
        this.showdate = event;
      }
      }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to be worried for **"which date-picker I should use?"** Go with any date-picker You like e.g. bootstrap date-picker, jQuery date-picker, native HTML5 date-picker etc.

Angular2 does not bind you with any specific library, it will automatically update its changes (not like Angular1).

I was using it as follows(just Bootstrap date-picker):

```
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Date of birth</label>
                      <input id="dobDatepicker" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" name="profile_dob" readonly="readonly"
                             style="cursor: pointer;background: #fff;border-bottom: 2px solid #d8d8d8;">
                      <p class="message-input error-input">
                        {{!dobDta?'Required':''}}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Inside controller:

```
jQuery('#dobDatepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        endDate:new Date(),
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
      }).change(()=>{
        this.dobDta=jQuery('#dobDatepicker').val();
      });
```

Thats it is was working. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was in the very same case two weeks ago as before I discovered PrimeNG, it's very handy and very well integrated in every Angular ecosystem (SystemJS, Webpack), it will work on Template Driven Forms and Model Driven Forms. Give it a try: http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Answer (score 0):

http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar 
It has every configuration you can possibly need and its native angular2 there is no jquery inside of it like other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the official angular/material library.

Example:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput type="date">
</md-input-container>
```

Complete code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular Material Plunker</title>

    <!-- Load common libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/2.0.3/typescript.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zone.js/0.6.25/zone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.38/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
    System
        .import('main.ts')
        .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

    <!-- Load the Angular Material stylesheet -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input-form-example>Loading Material Docs example...</input-form-example>
</body>

</html>


<!-- Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```